# Cannot guest ip addresses of guests

Tags: kvm, qemu, libvirt

I use kvm and libvirt and cannot get the ip address from the host:

The list from each of the guests is empty:

```
virsh domifaddr guest1

 Name       MAC address          Protocol     Address
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However I can gest the interfaces:

```
virsh domiflist guest1
Interface  Type       Source     Model       MAC
-------------------------------------------------------
macvtap1   direct     enp7s0f0   virtio      52:54:00:c4:52:1a
```

Packages versions are:

```
libvirt-daemon-kvm-3.9.0-14.el7_5.8.x86_64
qemu-kvm-common-1.5.3-156.el7_5.5.x86_64
qemu-kvm-1.5.3-156.el7_5.5.x86_64
kernel 3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64
libvirt-3.9.0-14.el7_5.8.x86_64
```

Why does not virsh shows anything? Beyond that networking on guests works well.

OS is CentOS 7.5.1804

Comment: Why should it need to show anything? The IP address belongs to the guest, not to the host. You might get an answer with `arp -na | grep -i '52:54:00:c4:52:1a' if the guest has been active on the network recently. But you might not.

Answer (score 3):

Try `virsh domifaddr --source agent` or `virsh domifaddr --source arp`. Since you are using macvtap for the VM, the default `--source lease` won't work, it only works for network `type='network'` configs that use dnsmasq